# Checking binaries security flags cross-platform

Tags: security, gcc

I implemented the GCC security flags mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9400582/1134813) and I want to do an automated test to check that my binaries have these flags enabled. On my machine I test using [checksec](https://github.com/slimm609/checksec.sh) script and hardened-check tool, but:

1. checksec does not work on macOS, it barely works on BSDs (with some modifications)
2. hardened-check is a perl script that must be deployed on every test machine with many dependencies(which I dislike) and it is also designed for Linux AFAIK

How can I automate this test on multiple UNIXes?

Thanks